# Vb.net Insert to accs

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

It says syntax error on INSERT INTO

```
Connection.Open()
Query = "INSERT INTO Admin (Username, Password, FullName, Office) Values ('" & TXT_USERNAME.Text & "','" & TXT_PASSWORD.Text & "','" & TXT_NAME.Text & "','" & CB_UNIT.Text & "');"
Command = New OleDbCommand(Query, Connection)
Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

The specific issue in this case is that `Password` is a reserved word in Jet/Access SQL.  In order to use a reserved word as an identifier, you need to escape it. In Jet/Access SQL, that means wrapping it in brackets:

```
INSERT INTO Admin (Username, [Password], FullName, Office) Values (...)
```

Some people prefer to escape all identifiers, just to be on the safe side.

There are other issues there too though.  Most importantly, you should learn how to use parameters in ADO.NET code.  As it stands, your code would crash your app with another syntax error if someone's full name was "John O'Brien".  Using parameters avoids issues with single-quotes, formatting of dates and numbers and, most importantly, protects against SQL injection attacks.  Learn the proper way IMMEDIATELY.